# MergeSort - Divide a sequence in 2 sub sequences not equal

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

A question from a test:

the division of the array its not regular.
the array will be divided in 2 not equal sub sequences:

- `(n/3)` the first subsequence
- `(2/3)*n` the second subsequence

Calculate the cost of mergetsort.

How can I resolve/deal with problems like these when the division is not regular?

```
mid = (start + last)/3;
mergesort (array , start , mid);
mergesort (array , mid+1 , last); 
fusione (array , start , mid , last); cost =  theta(n)
```

Comment: It should still be O(log n)

Comment: in the normal case : I have 1 sequence that in every level is divided by 2. 
So if I go to the master theorem I realize that the cost of the mergesort (the 2 recusive calls) + fusione, costs Theta (n^e log n) where (e = 1) so, i'll get , Theta (n log n).

But if i turn to my case, I know that i'm dividing in 2 the sequence, but they are not equivalent in size.

dividing the original sequence in 2 non equivalent sizes, cause the algorithm to work slower than the original version because every time it gets a different portion.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by writing out a recurrence relation. You'll split the problem into subarrays of size n / 3 and 2n / 3, and then in the merge step still do linear work to combine them. That gives the recurrence

> T(0) = 1
>
> T(n) = T(n / 3) + T(2n / 3) + Θ(n)

The question now is how to solve the recurrence relation. I'm going to claim that this is Θ(n log n). To see this, we'll prove that it's Ω(n log n) and that it's O(n log n) by using the recursion tree method.

Think about expanding out this recursion using a recursion tree. Notice that

- The top layer does Θ(n) work.
- The next layer has a subcall of size n / 3 and a subcall of size 2n / 3, which collectively do Θ(n) work.
- The layer below that has a subcall of size n / 9, a subcall of size 2n / 9, a second subcall of size 2n / 9, and a final subcall of size 4n / 9. Collectively, they do Θ(n)  work.

More generally, up until the point where the n / 3 branches die off, the top layers of the tree all do Θ(n) work. The number of layers before you start to have the recursion die off is roughly log<sub>3</sub> n, so the work done is at least Ω(n log n) due to Θ(log n) layers doing Θ(n) work.

You can also notice that the work per layer is always O(n), because the size of the subproblems is always no greater than the size of the subproblems on the previous layer (it's equal for the first few layers, then drops as those layers drop off). Therefore, an upper bound will be O(nL), where L is the total number of layers. The slowest problem to shrink shrinks by a factor of 2/3 at each layer, so there will be O(log n) total layers. This gives an upper bound of O(n log n).

Since the work is O(n log n) and Ω(n log n), it's therefore Θ(n log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Super post, thanks a lot for articulating it so well.

Comment: Thank You very much for explaining to me all of this, its very helpful, i want to prove it mathematically, its kind of hard thing for me, so together i think we'll make it.
by the way i draw the recursion tree - the first 3 recursion calls.

T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + Θ(n) ->  ((Θ(n) will be replaced to c*n)

Comment: Here's a hint: write T(n) = cn log n + dn + k and try using induction. I'll leave the rest as an exercise since this looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer will be - **n log<sub>3/2</sub> n**

Because it is a result of `T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + Θ(n)` equation